# Django url with params(int), don't know how to test, i tried but failed

Tags: django, testing

can anyone give help me how to test the following url in django?

```py
path('sendtokitchen/<int:table_number>/', send_to_kitchen, name='sendtokitchen'),
```

So far I have this, but it does not contains the param, therefore it fails.

```py
def test_sendtokitchen_url_is_resolves(self):
    url = reverse('sendtokitchen', kwargs={'table_number': 1})
    self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func, send_to_kitchen)
```

Comment: works for me (django 3.2.x). Which django version are you using?